# import pytesseract error in F:drive in python while path variable is set

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have installed pytesseract using pip install pytesseract and then importing in C: drive it does not give any error but when importing in F: drive it gives error:

```
F:\pythonMy>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytesseract
13
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .pytesseract import (
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 23, in <module>
from numpy import ndarray
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
from .numerictypes import object_
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 960, in <module>
_register_types()
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 955, in _register_types
numbers.Integral.register(integer)
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

I have also installed Tesseract-OCR and path variable sets :[image: path system variable]

How to fix this??